# .net winform talking to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, communication, local-storage

Im currently working on registration of our application. Basically we have a simple concurrent licensing system so when the user logs in we store their computer name and logon name to uniquely identify them. This is done from a simple winforms app that allows us to retrieve this data.

We now have a brother silverlight project that must work in the same licensing. The situation being that if a user logs into the winforms app they will use one license and if they log in on our silverlight app it will still use the one license because they are accessing it from the same computer.

The problem is that we cannot retrieve the clients machine and logon name with the silverlight application.

Can anybody think of a way of handling this? Or am i going bout it totally the wrong way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forms or Windows authentication.

Once authenticated you can retrieve anything you want (such as user claims, user profile...etc) which is provided through a web service. This of course mean you are communicating with some database somewhere.